# async/await fetch API call that maintains the order

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I want to make an async fetch call with await operator. A forEach method iterates over an array of API endpoints, then inserts some values into a local object. See below.

It works great, except - sometimes the values entered into dataModel[index].retailers[i+1] does not align with the index. For example, products for  api object 2 will be inserted into local object 4.

I think this has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the request, I thought await might resolve it but it hasn't. Can anyone show me the way?

```js
var api_obj;
// Defining async function
async function getapi(url, index) { // Storing response
  var response = await fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => api_obj = data)
    .then(function() {

      //iterate over the API object and store required values 
      //in our local dataModel object
      Object.keys(api_obj[0].RetailerProducts).forEach(function(i) {
        var i = parseInt(i, 10)
        dataModel[index].retailers[i + 1] = {
          retailer: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[i].RetailerName,
          url: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[i].ClickThruUrl,
          price: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[i].Price.toFixed(2),
          logo: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[i].RetailerLogoUrl,
          name: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[i].RetailerProductName
        }
      })

    });

}

//iterate over dataModel and call each API endpoint
Object.keys(dataModel).forEach(function(i) {
  // Calling that async function
  getapi(dataModel[i].apiEndpoint, i);
})
```

Here is what dataModel looks like:

```js
var dataModel = {
  '1': {
    'retailers': {}
  },
  '2': {
    'retailers': {}
  },
  '3': {
    'retailers': {}
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not the solution to your question but I have one suggestion for you to use let and const in place of var whenever needed.

Comment: In this part: `.forEach(function(i) {`  the `i` isn't an index number, it's the 1st parameter which is a value. The second parameter is the index number. If your intention was to use the index number then you must add both parameters in the `()` ex. `.forEach(function(e, i) {`

Comment: Is `api_obj[0].RetailerProducts` an array or an object? If an array, no need to do "object.keys." Some more details about the data shapes would be helpful to add to your original question, including the shape of `dataModel`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the feedback - I have added the structure of dataModel to the post @Allxie - hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the ordering issue, here was the solution, basically utilising another `.then` method that calls the next function and a counter sitting in global scope:

```js
var apiCounter = 1;

let csApiCall = () => {
  var api_obj;
  // Defining async function
  async function getapi(url, index) { // Storing response
    var response = await fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => api_obj = data)
      .then(function() {

        //iterate over the object and store required values 
        //in our dataModel object
        Object.keys(api_obj[0].RetailerProducts).forEach(function(k) {
          var k = parseInt(k, 10)
          dataModel[index].retailers[k + 1] = {
            retailer: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[k].RetailerName,
            url: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[k].ClickThruUrl,
            price: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[k].Price.toFixed(2),
            logo: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[k].RetailerLogoUrl,
            name: api_obj[0].RetailerProducts[k].RetailerProductName
          }
        })

      })
      .then(function() {

        if (apiCounter < Object.keys(dataModel).length) {
          apiCounter++;
          getapi(dataModel[apiCounter].apiEndpoint, apiCounter);
        }

      });

  }

  getapi(dataModel[apiCounter].apiEndpoint, apiCounter);

};
```